# jquery autocomplete complex html Result

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, asp.net-core

I need an autocomplete text box for my search and I will use jQuery UI for this. I'm using an ASP.NET Core API to get search result in json format. My search result should be grouping with bootstrap collapse panel and group members showing in a table. Every group has different fields and then has different tables. What is the best solution for this case? Thanks.

```
 $('#SearchTextBox').autocomplete({
                        source: 'api/user/search/'
                    });
```

Comment: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data and https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Answer (score 0):

My answer may be super late. But i hope this would help some one else. Basically i created this in mvc-5. You should modify it according to your needs.

```
$("#txtsearchpatient").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("SearchPatient")',
                dataType: "json",
                data: { search: $("#txtsearchpatient").val() },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.length > 0) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                id: item.Id,
                                value: item.Name
                            };
                        }));
                    }
                    else {
                        $("#emptysearchdiv").hide();
                        var result = [
                            {
                                id:0,
                                label: 'No matches found',
                                value: ""
                            }
                        ];
                        response(result);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function (event, ui) {
    $(this).val(ui.item.value);

    var value = ui.item.value;
    var id = ui.item.id;
        },
        search: function (e, u) {
            $(this).addClass('loader');
        },
        response: function (e, u) {
            $(this).removeClass('loader');
        }
    });




public JsonResult SearchPatient(string search)
    {
        Regex RE_Numbers = new Regex(@"^\d+$");
        if(RE_Numbers.IsMatch(search) == true)
        {
            var sdsds = db.Patient.Where(x => 
 x.PhoneNumber.Contains(search)).Select(x => new {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = "Name: " + x.Name + " | " + "EmailId: " + x.EmailId + " | " + 
 "Phone: " + x.PhoneNumber + " | " + "Age: " + x.Age
            }).ToList();
            return Json(sdsds, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else if(search.Contains("@") == true || search.Contains(".com") == true)
        {
            var sdsds = db.Patient.Where(x => x.EmailId.Contains(search)).Select(x => 
new {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = "Name: " + x.Name + " | " + "EmailId: " + x.EmailId + " | " + 
"Phone: " + x.PhoneNumber + " | " + "Age: " + x.Age
            }).ToList();
            return Json(sdsds, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        else
        {
            var sdsds = db.Patient.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(search)).Select(x => 
new {
                Id = x.Id,
                Name = "Name: " + x.Name + " | " + "EmailId: " + x.EmailId + " | " + 
"Phone: " + x.PhoneNumber + " | " + "Age: " + x.Age
            }).ToList();
            return Json(sdsds, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Dont forget to include jquery.ui.css & jquery.ui.js